# How can I create a document with inputs from cells of a spreadsheet? Please refer the link/pic for more details?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

How can I create a document with inputs from cells of a spreadsheet? Please refer the link/pic for more details.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmdpB.png)

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts. Reference [ask].

Answer (score 0):

**This might help you to get started:**

```
function makeDoc(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('myDoc');
  var vA=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var name=vA[0][0];
  var doc=DocumentApp.create(name);
  var body=doc.getBody();
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++){
    body.appendParagraph(vA[i][0]);
  }
  var root=DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var files=root.getFilesByName(name);
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var child=files.next();
  }
  var newFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById('finalFolderId');
  newFolder.addFile(child)
  root.removeFile(child);
}
```

Comment: While I run this code, It shows error as such : 1)"Invalid argument: name (line 6, file "Code"): "var doc=DocumentApp.create(name);2) Cannot find method addFile((class)). (line 17, file "Code").""

Comment: I suggest that you dig in to the debugger and figure it out.